# How can I add checkboxes in restaurant CRUD project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a CRUD project. The purpose here is to subject an order to create, read, update and delete operations. In this project, there is a sauces page and also a menus page. My goal is to have the added sauces appear as checkboxes on the menu definition page. How can I do this ?

Sauces domain:

```
namespace MVC_Hamburger_Project.Models.Domain
{
    public class ExtraSauce
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string SauceName { get; set; }
        public double SaucePrice { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfSacue { get; set; }
        public Guid? MenuId { get; set; }
        public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Menu domain :

```
namespace MVC_Hamburger_Project.Models.Domain
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public string MenuDescription { get; set; }
        public double MenupPrice { get; set; }
        public double NumberOfMenu { get; set; }
        public List<ExtraSauce> extraSauces { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried like below but it doesn't work :

```
@model MVC_Hamburger_Project.Models.AddMenuViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add";
}

<h1>Add</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Add">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MenuName" class="control-label">Menu Name</label>
                <input asp-for="MenuName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MenuName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MenuDescription" class="control-label">Menu Description</label>
                <input asp-for="MenuDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MenuDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MenupPrice" class="control-label">Menu Price</label>
                <input asp-for="MenupPrice" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MenupPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfMenu" class="control-label">Number of Menu</label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfMenu" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfMenu" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

             <table>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            @Model[i].Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
             </table>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I tried to add sauces as a checkbox to the menu adding page with the for loop above.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see your ViewModel, but to my understanding you want to iterate list of extraSauces, not the models collection itself. Assuming you have a property `List<ExtraSauce>` in ViewModel, and ExtraSauce has property `<bool>IsSelected` maybe that works:

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.extraSauces.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.extraSauces[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.extraSauces[i].IsSelected)
            </td>
            
            <td>
            @Model.extraSauces[i].Name
            </td>
            </tr>
    }
</table>
```

In my project I use:

```
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
```

where `Selected` is bool property.